# How do i print out number variables in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let me preface this by saying that I'm very new to coding in general.
I'm going to paste my code here and I just want to know what's wrong with it. It is meant to be a calculator for BMI.

```
    import math

    print('input your height and weight to find BMI.')

    num_a = int(input("feet=="))
    num_b = int(input("inches=="))
    num_c = int(input("weight(lbs)=="))

    def weight():
        int(num_c) * 2.2 

    def height():
        (int(num_a)) * 12 + int(num_b)

    def height_meters():
        (int(height)) * 0.0254

    def height_meters_sq():
        math.sqrt(int(height_meters))

    def bmi():
        (int(weight)) / int(height_meters_sq)

    print("Your BMI is..")
    print(bmi)
```

Whenever the print function at the end runs, all that pops up is

> function bmi at 0x7f2971a3e268

I'll appreciate any help/criticism, as I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are you asking exactly? There's a lot to address here, and unfortunately, StackOverflow is not a tutorial service, but rather, it's for asking/answering *specific* coding questions. You may consider something like reddit for these open-ended questions

Comment: You seem to miss some basic knowledge in Python. I would recommend going over one of the many tutorials online for this. This site is for answering questions about code problems, not teaching it

Comment: Note: you're multiplying the entered weight in lbs by 2.2, which is wrong.

Comment: Hi @glitched and welcome to the site. It is not necessary to edit a note in the question saying your problem is resolved nor writing an answer stating that for that matter. If there is an answer that helped you solve your problem, feel free to up-vote it and mark it as accepted to show both your appreciation and that the problem is solved. Consider taking the [tour] and reading [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is that you are calling functions as they were variables

Here is your code with the functions being called correctly:

```
import math

print('input your height and weight to find BMI.')

num_a = int(input("feet=="))
num_b = int(input("inches=="))
num_c = int(input("weight(lbs)=="))

def weight():
    return int(num_c) * 2.2

def height():
    return (int(num_a)) * 12 + int(num_b)

def height_meters():
    return (int(height())) * 0.0254

def height_meters_sq():
    return math.sqrt(int(height_meters()))

def bmi():
    return (int(weight())) / int(height_meters_sq())

print("Your BMI is..")
print(bmi())
```

The result:

```
input your height and weight to find BMI.
feet==10
inches==5
weight(lbs)==10
Your BMI is..
22.0
```

The other problem in your code, is that your functions where not returning the values. In python, the default return value from a function is None (null), so if you don't return the value, when you print the bmi(), it will simply print `None`